# What's wrong with my bit vector?

Tags: java, algorithm, bit-manipulation, bit, bitvector

I am trying to create a bit vector backed by an `int[]`.
So I have the following code:

```
public class BitVector {  

  int[] vector = new int[1 << 16];  

  public void setBit(int nextInt) {  
    nextInt = nextInt & 0xFFFF;  
    int pos = nextInt / 32;  
    int offset = nextInt % 32;  
    vector[pos] |= (1 << offset);    
  }

  public int findClearedBit() {  

    for(int i = 0;  i < vector.length; i++){              
            for(int j = 0; j < 8; j++){  
                if((vector[i] & (1 << j)) == 0)   
            return i * 32 +  j;  
        }  
    }  

    return -1;  
   }  

}
```

I know that perhaps I should have used `byte[]` instead etc but I was wondering why this way it does not work.
The idea is that I pass in `int` from a stream and keep the lower 16 bits and mark the corresponding bit as set. So when I iterate over the vector I will find the number (indicate by the lower 16 bits) missing.
But I get wrong result. So I believe my handing is wrong.
Any ideas?

**Update:**
I have a stream of 32-bit integers. As I read them in I try to mark a number missing by *using the lower 16-bits* and setting the bitvector (code posted).
I also try to find the upper 16 bits missing reading the stream a second time.
So while the missing number is:  `231719592` = (`1101110011111100001010101000`)  = (`3535`-`49832`)
When I read the stream I don't get `49832` as the missing lower bits but `65536`

**Update2:**

```
public int findMissingInt(File f)throws Exception{  
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(f);  
    int SIZE = 1 << 16; 
    int[] occurences = new int[SIZE];  
    while(sc.hasNext()){  
    occurences[getIdx(sc.nextInt())]++;  
    }  

    int missingUpper = -1;  
    for(int i = 0; i < occurences.length; i++){  
    if(occurences[i] < SIZE){  
        System.out.println("Found upper bits:"+i);  
        missingUpper = i;  
        break;  
    }  
    }
    if(missingUpper == -1){   
    return -1;  
    }  
    //Arrays.fill(occurences, 0);  //I reused this. Bellow changed after answer of Peter de Rivaz 
    BitVector v = new BitVector(new int[1 << (16-5)]);  
    sc = new Scanner(f);
    while(sc.hasNext()){  
    v.setBit(sc.nextInt());  
    }  

    int missingLower = v.findClearedBit();
    System.out.println("Lower bits:"+missingLower);   
    return createNumber(missingUpper, missingLower);  

}   


private int createNumber(int missingUpper, int missingLower) {  
        int result = missingUpper;  
        result = result << 16;  

        return result | missingLower;  
}  



public int getIdx(int nextInt) {          
    return (nextInt >>> 16);        
}
```

I get:

```
Missing number=231719592  
Found upper bits:3535 //CORRECT  
Lower bits:-1  //WRONG
Actual missing number=-1  //WRONG
```

Comment: Are you doing this for fun? Because there is a built-in [`BitSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html) in Java.

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz:Practicing for interviews.

Comment: I am not very clear on what you are trying to do, can you provide a couple of sample input /output which are expected

Comment: Your code works fine for me.

Comment: @DanteisnotaGeek:Please see updated OP

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think there are two problems:

1. Your array has 65536 entries, but you store 32 bits in each entry, so you only need 65536/32 entries in it.
2. You store 32 bits in each int, but only check j from 0 to 7 when finding gaps

The first bug means that your program reports 65536 as a missing 16bit number.
The second bug means that your program does not spot the missing number.

i.e. change

```
int[] vector = new int[1 << 16];
```

to

```
int[] vector = new int[1 << (16-5)];
```

and change

```
for(int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
```

to

```
for(int j = 0; j < 32; j++)
```

### EDIT

Judging from the comments, the question is actually how to find a missing number with limited RAM.  The answer to this question can be found [here on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6164597/algorithm-question-on-file-search-indexing).

There is an additional bug in the higher level code.

During the second pass that populates the bitset, you should only include numbers that have the matching upper bits.

i.e. change

```
v.setBit(sc.nextInt());
```

to something like

```
int nx = sc.nextInt();
if (getIdx(nx)==missingUpper)
  v.setBit(nx);
```

Comment: `Your array has 65536 entries, but you store 32 bits in each entry` But I do `nextInt = nextInt & 0xFFFF;` so I get 16 bits per entry, right?

Comment: Yes, but you also do pos = nextInt / 32, so you only get 11 bits of choices for pos (which is the thing used to index the array)

Comment: But this only affects the program in that the array allocated is bigger than needed, right?Or am I missing something here?

Comment: It makes the array allocated too big, and also means that you loop over too many values of i, so that your program will always return 65536 instead of -1 in the case that all the values in the bitset are populated.

Comment: You are right on `j<32`. But if I do the changes you suggest now I get `-1` as result

Comment: How many numbers do you have in the stream?  My concern is that the program is actually doing the correct thing and perhaps you have another number in the stream with the bottom 16 bits equal to 49832

Comment: I have created a file with all the numbers from `0-299,999,999` i.e the first 300 million numbers except `231,719,592` and I am trying to find it this way when reading in the file

Comment: So the problem is that when you input the number 49832 this will set the bit in the array.  If you are trying to detect a missing 32bit number you should increase the size of the array from 1<<(16-5) to 1<<(32-5) and remove the nextInt = nextInt & 0xFFFF

Comment: This is a practice question and the requirement is to solve it assuming I have `2MB` RAM. So I am breaking upper 16 bits and lower 16 bits

Comment: `49832` actually should not be found as part of the stream since it is the last 16 bits of the missing number

Comment: I suggest you look at the link I posted in my answer.  I suspect you are using a flawed algorithm that is reading other numbers which have the same bottom 16 bits as the missing number and it is these other numbers which are causing the bit to be set.  If you disagree, then perhaps you should post the rest of your algorithm in the question.

Comment: You are the best!So I should only restrict to the lower 16-bits of numbers that are part of the set?